# Force Git to use the default system language

Tags: git, macos, sublimetext3, homebrew, config

Git isn't using English as default language in my system and I can't figure out why. I'm on macOS 10.13.6 and using the last Git installed with Homebrew.

In some apps that have git integration, natively or with a package, like Sublime Text or Fork, some git messages are provided in Spanish.

[image: Cambiando a rama...]
[image: The dates are provided in Spanish]
[image: Nada que hacer?]

My system was installed in English, and English is the main language os the system. I have Spanish set as secondary language in the system and a Spanish keyboard, though.

I'm Spanish and I understand the messages, but I have everything setup in English and I don't know why this messages are popping up.

On terminal everything is English and in the `.bash_profile`  I have set up:

```sh
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

I'm wondering if there is any hidden setting somewhere or something that can be causing this.

Thoughts?

PS1/ I just uninstalled and installed git and nothing has changed.

PS2/ In sublime if you are using the package GitSavvy you can feed git environment variables. If you put there

```
    "env": { 
        "LANG": "en_US.UTF-8" 
    },
```

Git works in the correct language. It isn't a solution thought.

PS3/ this is related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337244/homebrew-and-git-wrong-language-on-the-command-line

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but on MacOS applications that are started via `launchctl` (i.e. anything on the dock) don't get their environment from the `.bash_profile`. As a test, try quitting these applications entirely and then launching them from a terminal window instead and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Thanks @OdatNurd the problem, as I answered down here is other. It's related to Homebrew's Git and the locales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figure it out!

The problem only happens with Homebrew's Git and seems that have been several comments and issues in the Homebrew's issue tracker ([#37331](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/37331), [#31980](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/31980) and this particular [comment](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/31980#issuecomment-425894125)) that sadly haven't been addressed by Homebrew's team.

The problem arises then Homebrew's Git is installed in a system where English is the default language and there is also other secondary languages. It seems to be related to [gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/).

There are a couple of solutions:

1. Install the original Git binary. If you are Homebrew user this is a poor solution since you probably like to have everything installed with Homebrew for convenience.
2. Parse language environmental variables to the apps affected when they call Git. This was possible in with Sublime Text's Savvy package, but perhaps it isn't always possible.
   For terminal is easy. You just add to your terminal profile `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zshrc` or whatever:

```sh
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

I tried to make this system wide without avail inserting those in my `~/.bashrc` and in `/etc/bashrc` and `/etc/profile`.  More info about this [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/98913/91367). Perhaps you have better luck.
   Anyhow, if you have another user in your computer that uses other language that isn't English, this isn't good.

3. Delete/rename the ofender language locale/s in the Git's keg on Homebrew's Cellar `/usr/local/Cellar/git/X.XX.xx/share/locale` in my case was the `es` one. I decided to rename it adding just a `.back`  and you can do it easily with this command every time Git gets updated

```sh
$ find $(brew --prefix)/Cellar/git -type d -name "es" -print0 | xargs -I{} mv {} {}.back
```

You just have to replace `es` by your locale and it will rename to `your-locale.back`.

Answer (score 0):

This may well be a bug in Git. I've seen this in other applications. What happens is the program author will write the base program in English, and then provide translation files to other languages, but will *not* provide an `en_US` translation file, because why do that when the base program is already in English, right? Then what happens is the localization library (gettext) looks through your list of preferred languages from your system, looking for a translation file in the git program for each. It doesn't find one for English, but there's one for Spanish, so it uses that!

What needs to happen to get the program to work correctly in situations like yours is that the program needs to provide a translation file for `en_US`, *even though* the base program is already written in English.

You should report this as a bug upstream to Git.

Comment: It's a problem with the homebrew installation... mostly, but the brew maintainers don't agree. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55160216/6888648

Comment: I don't think I agree either. Homebrew is not doing anything to cause the `en` translation to be absent. They are simply building git with `gettext` support enabled, while the Git-supplied download is not built with `gettext` support. The various actions discussed in those linked issues and in your answer are all just workarounds to the underlying problem of how the absent `en` translation interacts with users with multiple preferred languages defined. And that's an issue with `git` itself: you can see the missing `en` in the `po/` directory of the `git` source tree.